# White row below main menu and above jumbotron

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

White row appeared below main menu and above jumbotron on a drupal site. I am unable to remove it.
I think that it is css problem but I can't find what exactly causing it. Here is the link to codepen: https://codepen.io/lomachx/pen/WNbLgYa

```
 <body class="html front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-node i18n-ru">
    <div id="skip-link" class="skip-link">
        <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-wrap">  
        <div class="full-wrap logo-wrap"><!--c-->
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="/ru" title="Main"><img src="img/logo.png"/></a>
            </div>
        <h1 id="site-title">
            <a href="/ru" title="Main">Cool Site</a>
        </h1>
            <nav id="main-menu"  role="navigation">
                <a class="nav-toggle" href="#">Navigation</a>
                <div class="menu-navigation-container">
                    <ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/ru" title=""    class="active">Main</a></li>
                        <li class="leaf"><a href="/ru/articles" title="">Articles</a></li>
                        <li class="last leaf"><a href="/ru/about">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header"><!--c-->  
    <div class="homebanner">  
    </div>
    <!--New navbar -->
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar-lower" role="navigation">
            <div class="region region-second-menu">
                <div id="block-system-navigation" class="block block-system block-menu">
                    <div class="content">
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li class="first last leaf"><a href="/ru" title=""     class="active">Главная</a></li>
                        </ul>  
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- /.block -->
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>   
</div>
<div class="bckgr-wrap">
  <div><H1>Nest</H1></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change body `margin-top:50px` to the height of your header like below

**css**

```
body {
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 180%;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
```